# Bibliography after appendix

Tags: bibliographies, appendix

My main LaTeX file has the following structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \mainmatter
  \input{intro}

  \input{chap1}
  \input{chap2}
  \input{chap3}
  \input{chap4}
  \input{chap5}
  \input{chap6}
  \input{chap7}

  \begin{appendix}
    \input{appendix1}
    \input{appendix2}
  \end{appendix}


  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{db.bib}

  \input{acknowledgements}

\end{document}
```

The output PDF considers the bibliography as an appendix, since it writes "Appendix C" on the same page of the references. In the table of contents, the bibliography is also listed as "C Bibliography".

How do I tell LaTeX not to consider it as an appendix?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Done. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I had to write "appendices" instead of "appendix" and get rid of

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```